# Can an Android app provide an implementation of a class to a library?

Tags: java, android

I've got an Android library (MyLib) with a class, **MyEditText**, which, depending on build flavor, either extends either **android.widget.EditText**, or **com.some.thirdparty.EditText**. It's instanced within the library (in code and XML layouts) as **com.my.company.MyEditText**.

Now what I want to do is have my app, which uses MyLib, provide the 3rd-party implementation (and the library it needs) instead, without changing all the library's references to MyEditText.

How best to accomplish this?

Comment: Define an interface in the library and use it in the methods provided by the library. In the main application you can implement this interface and create instance(s) of this class. Use the instance when calling methods on the library.

Comment: Thanks, but will that cover uses in XML files?

Comment: I'm looking at having the app override the ClassLoader, as is done here: https://github.com/simpleton/AndroidDynamicLoader